# Google libPhoneNumber throwing invalid phone number

Tags: android, android-studio, libphonenumber

As i mentioned in title i have few indian numbers, some of numbers are working correct but some numbers starting from 635 (Vodafone series) are not working. when i entered number to check number is valid or not using libPhoneNumber params .isValidNumber(number), it's throw invalid number. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

example: checking one number +919900000000 is valid but checking the number starting with 6359...... or 6355..... Overall starting with 635 number throwing invalid number.

```
 public static boolean validMobile(String phoneNumberE164Format) {
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    try {
        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumberE164Format, null);
        return phoneUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumberProto) && phoneUtil.isPossibleNumber(phoneNumberProto); // returns true if valid
    } catch (NumberParseException e) {
        System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You're in a beginner stage I guess.. Post some relevant code about the regex that you are using in .isValidNumber(number).

Comment: @EngineSense take a look

Comment: Is that PhoneNumberUtil is your own logic code? If post that code too. Or Library paste that link too.

Comment: @EngineSense No it's a library which is provided by Google [link](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber)

Comment: phoneUtil.formatNumber(String phoneNumber, String defaultCountryIso), Can you try with this?

Comment: @EngineSense tried but not work. It's vodafone number, when i checked on google vodafone starting number series list there is nothing with 6359 in india. Check this [link](https://www.smsgatewaycenter.com/blog/list-vodafone-mobile-number-series-india)

Comment: I have not tried PhoneNumberUtil in android, I worked with regex to sort out this issue, Check with regex with like this r'^[6-9][0-9]{9}$',. This will match starting with digit 6 and above and use prefix +91 before saving to database.